# Testing approximate equality of two doubles

Tags: math, double

Given these two double values

```
double d1 = 1.0E-24;
double d2 = 1.0000000000000029E-24;
```

and the following function

```
public static boolean isEqual(double d0, double d1, double epsilon) {
    return d0 == d1 ? true : Math.abs(d0 - d1) < epsilon;
}
```

How can I calculate the smallest epsilon (the least double distance) so that the term `Math.abs(d0 - d1) < epsilon` evaluates to true?

**edited in response to comment:**

I'm aware of the method `Double.doubleToRawLongBits` but still need some clarification which bits I need to compare. 
So the binary representation of both double values is

`d1: 0 11101011110 0011010101111100001010011001101010001000111010100111`

`d2: 0 11101011110 0011010101111100001010011001101010001000111010110111`

Do I just need to compare the mantissa bits like this?

```
isEqual(getMantissaLongBits(d1), getMantissaLongBits(d2), epsilon(getMantissaLongBits(d1), getMantissaLongBits(d2),49))? 

private static long getMantissaLongBits(double x) {
    return Double.doubleToRawLongBits(x) & 0x000fffffffffffffL;
}

public static double epsilon(final double one, final double other, final int bits) {
    return Math.max(Math.scalb(Math.max(Math.abs(one), Math.abs(other)), -bits),
            Math.scalb(Double.MIN_NORMAL, 52 - bits));
}
```

Comment: Make epsilon a constant such as: 
`public static final double epsilon = [whatever your threshold is]`

Comment: Epsilon should not be something you have to calculate it should be a constant threshold that says "if the difference between two doubles is less than this threshold they are equal enough."

Comment: OK I got it, thanks. But let's say I want to choose an epsilon such that at least n bits of both doubles are equal. Since a double has a 52 bit mantissa I would like to pass a variable epsilon between 48-51 bits. How can epsilon be calculated in this case?

Comment: To do bitwise calculations you will want to use a method in the Double object method doubleToLongRawBits: `Double.doubleToLongRawBits(d1)` See documentation here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToRawLongBits(double)

Comment: See my edited post